# Saving data from arrays into csv file

Tags: python, csv

I made a program to save two arrays into csv file using pandas data frame in python so that I could record all the data.

I tried the code listed below.

```
 U_8=[]
 start=[]
 U_8.append(d)
 start.append(str(time.time()))
 x=pd.DataFrame({'1st':U_8,  'Time Stamp':start})
 export_csv = x.to_csv (r'/home/pi/Frames/q8.csv', index = None, 
 header=True)
```

Every time the program is closed and run again , it overwrites the previous values stored in the csv file. I expected it to save the new values along with the previous ones. How could I store the past and present value in this csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to append to a csv instead of writing, pass `mode='a'` to `df.to_csv`. The default mode is `'w'` which overwrites any existing csv with the same filename. Plain appending, however, appends the column headers as well which will appear as values in your csv. To mitigate that, pass `header=False` in your subsequent runs: `df.to_csv(data, mode='a', header=False)`.
Another way is to read your original DataFrame and use `pd.concat` to join it with your new results. The workflow will then be as such:

1. Read the original csv into a DataFrame.
2. Create a DataFrame with new results.
3. Concatenate the two DataFrames.
4. Write the resulting DataFrame to csv.

Assigning the return value of `.to_csv` to a variable is not necessary. As in `df.to_csv(data)` will still export to csv.

Comment: How to make headers appear only once just at the beginning of the csv file.                                                                 export_csv = x.to_csv (r'/home/pi/Frames/q8.csv', index = None, mode='a', header=True)                                             I am getting this in the file,                                                   1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th,8th,Time Stamp
,,,,,,,,1559839922.71
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th,8th,Time Stamp
,,,,,,,,1559839922.73
I want the headers at the top of the file only.

Comment: @Bilal I wrote about two options available.
In the first one, you need to use two different `.to_csv` commands. One for the very first export with `headers=True`, one for the subsequent exports with `headers=False`. You could use something like `if os.path.isfile(csv):` to control which one is used.
The second method is basically reading in all the data everytime, combining it and overwriting the old csv with a new, bigger one.